# Getting the distribution $Y$ given that its MGF is $M_X(at)$ for a known distribution $X$.

Tags: probability

Suppose we know that a certain random variable $X$ has moment generating function
$$M_X(t),$$
and that another random variable $Y$ has moment generating function
$$M_Y(t)=M_X(at)$$
for some constant $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Can we get an explicit expression for the distribution of $Y$ given that of $X$?

For example if $X_i\sim Poisson(\lambda)$ are independent, I computed that
$$M_{X_i}(t)=e^{\lambda(e^t-1)},$$
and if
$$Y=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$
then
$$M_Y(t)=e^{n\lambda(e^{t/n}-1)}.$$
So $M_Y(t)=M_U(t/n)$ where $U\sim Poisson(\lambda n)$. Can we get the distribution of $Y$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every case will be that simple, but here's what I can say for sure. Suppose $M_{Y}(t) = M_{X}(at)$. Then
$$\mathbb{E}[e^{tY}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{atX}] = \mathbb{E}[e^{t(aX)}] = M_{aX}(t)\text{.}$$
So, in fact, $Y$ follows the same distribution as $aX$. This is a standard result in probability. In general, to find the distribution of $aX$, I would suggest
$$f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}\left(\dfrac{y}{a}\right)\left|\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}y}\left[\dfrac{y}{a}\right]\right| = \dfrac{1}{a}f_{X}\left(\dfrac{y}{a}\right)\text{.}$$

Your observation happens to work for the Poisson distribution because $\lambda$ is a **scale parameter** [someone correct me if my terminology is wrong]. I recall also that this applies to the Gamma distribution as well. I can't find a satisfactory source on this - there is a [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_parameter) on it.